# Customize Spring Security Internal WebClient

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

While working in a café hotspot Wifi, I have noticed that Spring Security is failing while resolving the JWK URI as set in `application.yml`:

```yaml
# application.yml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          jwk-set-uri: https://some.vendor.com/.well-known/jwks.json
```

I have noticed a similar behavior with another piece of code I own that uses `org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient`, which I was able to fix by changing the address resolver as in:

```kotlin
val jvmBlockingResolver = HttpClient.create().resolver(DefaultAddressResolverGroup.INSTANCE)
val webClient = WebClient
            .builder()
            .clientConnector(ReactorClientHttpConnector(jvmBlockingResolver))
            .build()
```

Digging inside Spring Security code, I have found the following lines:

```
// NimbusReactiveJwtDecoder.java
package org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt;

/* ... */

import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;

/* ... */

// line 383:
source.setWebClient(this.webClient);
```

Now I strongly believe that this error is because of this this `WebClient`. Is there a way to solve this problem?

I was thinking I could inject my `WebClient` bean, but now that I have seen the code, I don't think that will work. Am I looking in the wrong place? Is this a Spring Security limitation or a bug?

Comment: why not try using the builder https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/jwt/NimbusReactiveJwtDecoder.JwkSetUriReactiveJwtDecoderBuilder.html and set the webclient and build and return it to the framework as a bean.

Comment: @Toerktumlare thanks for the suggestion. It gave a glimpse of hope, but I am still stuck. The builder allows you to change the [WebClient](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/jwt/NimbusReactiveJwtDecoder.JwkSetUriReactiveJwtDecoderBuilder.html#webClient(org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient)), which internally uses Reactor's HttpClient. I have got some more insight on how this component works internally. If I prove it is not possible, I will try to make a feature request for Spring Security team.

Comment: @Toerktumlare I gave it another try and it worked :)
The bridge is `ReactorClientHttpConnector`. Is there a way to promote your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Toerktumlare comment, I was able to use his suggestion to create a custom bean:

```kotlin
@Bean
fun reactiveJwtDecoder(): ReactiveJwtDecoder {
    val jvmBlockingResolver = HttpClient.create().resolver(DefaultAddressResolverGroup.INSTANCE)
    val connector = ReactorClientHttpConnector(jvmBlockingResolver)
    val webClient = WebClient.builder().clientConnector(connector).build()
    return NimbusReactiveJwtDecoder.withJwkSetUri("https://example.com/.well-known/jwks.json")
        .webClient(webClient)
        .build()
}
```

Also it is possible to do this with the `SecurityWebFilterChain` builder:

```kotlin
.oauth2ResourceServer {
    val jvmBlockingResolver = HttpClient.create().resolver(DefaultAddressResolverGroup.INSTANCE)
    val connector = ReactorClientHttpConnector(jvmBlockingResolver)
    val webClient = WebClient.builder().clientConnector(connector).build()
    it.jwt().jwtDecoder(
        NimbusReactiveJwtDecoder
            .withJwkSetUri("https://example.com/.well-known/jwks.json")
            .webClient(webClient)
            .build()
    )

}
```